# Should I unplug my TV(which is turned off) during thunderstorm

Tags: electrical, television, surge-suppression, lightning

There is a common sense to unplug the expensive electronic devices during thunderstorm as lighting strike can affect the power lines and anything that's connected to powerline is going to be wasted.

But my doubt is should we unplug if the TV is turned off using switch in switch
& socket board.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: It depends on the amount of power pass though.  A decent power surge protector should be okay, but any other types of simple switch might not have enough air gap to prevent cross over of power.  A power surge protector placed in your panel should protect the whole house and the electronics in it, for about the same price as all the surge protectors you would need for different devices.  Unplugging of expensive devices is still the best, but remember to unplug the antenna/cable also.

Comment: @crip659 - Good advice. I do have DTH atenna so I will remember to unplug that also. But I never thought power could cross over the air gap. Interesting to know. But I should Install surge protector at house level

Comment: Not sure but the air gap in a standard wall switch might a bit over 1/2 inch.  Air gaps in smaller switches are probably less than half of that, which is good with standard house power.

Comment: i've seen lighting jump across a power strip switch and fry the computer+monitor+printer plugged into it; nothing's perfect, except unplugging.

Comment: @crip659 - that makes sense

Comment: @dandavis - I'm glad you mentioned it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, all electronics should be unplugged during a thunderstorm. There is no cheap surge protector better than an air gap. For that matter, in a direct strike there could be a threat to the house wiring.

But realistically, mist of us don't want to run around the house unplugging everything whenever a thunderstorm is predicted.m,never mind turning off the main breaker And most power surges are minor. So most folks either spend US$10 on a surge protector (often but not always built into a power strip) to protect their mist expensive device(s), or just play the odds and ignore the issue. I go with a mix of these. Some can protect from surges on a video cable as well,

It's possible to install a whole-house surge suppressor at the breaker box. These are aimed more at protecting the house than the devices but should help the latter as well. I'm not coming convinced that's worth the effort, but I've done so, on the "I can afford to waste $100 and it might help" principle.

If you're using an outside antenna, it should already have a lightning arrestor.bif not, install one.

Side note: Devices which run in "standby" mode when not in use, so they can respond to remote controls it start up more quickly, can add up to a significant power draw. It may be worth considering using a power strip with a switch and really turning them off when not in use, which will also improve surge protection. There are "smart" power strips which monitor one device and turn off the other outlets when that one goes below a minimum power draw; I use one in my home entertainment cluster for exactly this purpose, powering down everything else when the amplifier drops to standby.(Others might make the TV the master device, if that's your primary use )

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Whole House Surge Protector and Lightening arrestor. Thanks

Comment: this comment is spot on. Most modern household appliances/devices go to a power supply first. Old days they went through a power switch first. Now most things have internal clocks or rely on remotes so must have always on power supplies.

Answer (score 2):

To be safe, yes. The TV is always on. What that means is the power supply IS energized providing power so the IR receiver for the remote works, so the power button works etc. The display might be off, but it (the TV) is in fact on.

If you're trying to ensure you have ZERO chance of an issue due to power problems. Unplug it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I mean tv is switched off using hard button in switch board. Should I still unplug the cable ?

Comment: do you mean to say ? Even if the switch in the switch board is turned off .. there would some electricity still in the TV ?

Comment: What I mean is that the TV, when plugged into a powered wall outlet is always ON. The tv produces power used by internal circuitry to power the sensors to detect remotes etc. The screen might be off, but that power supply is on.

Comment: Got it , I think this applies for always on power socket not power switch cum socket based power supply

Comment: Just to be clear, think of a microwave. You SEE the clock, so you know it is on. when it is not being used.

Everything that you "turn on" with a remote is never really off.  If you have a regular everyday lamp, it is either off or on. If you have a lamp that you touch the base to turn on/off, it is ever actually off

Comment: understood , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This depends heavily on your local environment.
Is your house in middle of nowhere, powered by aerial wires?
Or is it a part of neighborhood, and all the wires are underground?
In first case, you will want some kind of lightning strike protection - normally installed in the main supply panel of whole house.
Second, in all cases, you will still want a surge suppressor - it looks like a power strip, but has fuses. Make sure you are buying an actual surge suppressor - it will have rating in Joules aka how much punishment can it take before passing the overvoltage to your more sensitive devices.
Connect your sensitive equipment to surge suppresor - TV, stereo, computers. Do not connect space heaters, power tools and other 'dumb' loads that don't have sensitive electronics.

Finally, make sure the antenna to your TV has a brand thunder strike suppresor, or better, disconnect the antenna when storm is expected (and leave the plug some distance from the socket).
You could also dump tv altogether and use streaming services.
If your internet is not fiber or cable company, make sure it has a surge suppresor too.

Comment: My neighbourhood has aerial wires for electricity/cable tv/fibre internet connection

Comment: Actually, fuses aren't what does the job in a surge protector; it's metal oxide varistors, MOVs, which typically shunt surges over about 600V. They may burn out in the process of doing so, so they're similar to fuses in being considered sacrificial components, but are quite different otherwise (and generally not designed to be easily replaced; if they go, thank them for their sacrifice and replace the whole unit.)

Comment: Yeah, everything's overhead here too. Downside of being in a neighborhood built in the late 19th century; wire is an afterthought (never mind optical).

Comment: @keshlam I'm not saying fuses are the protecting element. Its just an indicator to tell surge protector from regular power strip. If it doesnt have fuses, it probably isnt surge protector, regardless what box says.

Comment: I'm saying you're wrong. Look up MOV'S.

Comment: @keshlam Sure, let us go into debate and ask user to see MOVs *through* the unit casing so they can tell. All I am saying - if it has fuses and Joule rating, it is a surge suppresor. Power strips usually don't have fuses, because manufacturers dont add them nilly-willy to bump cost. Surge suppresors should have fuses, if they don't, its a shitty suppresor.

Comment: If it hase a joule rating, it is a surge suppressor. Many power strips without one, in my experience, do have a fuse or breaker and we agree that any strip without one is an inferior strip. So we're mostly in agreement.

Comment: @keshlam - if the surge protector has jules marked , then that means the Surge protector has MOV right and it also means it can prevent voltage spikes due to electrical grid or lightning strikes ?

Comment: @keshlam - I couldn't see any MOV or Jules mentioned in this [product](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08T5T6ZYC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1) Can you please let me know your opinion.

Comment: I would assume there is a reason it does not claim to be a surge suppressor, only a "spike guard", unless the two are synonymous in India, which I have no way of knowing. Beyond that, I have no reason to know. I'm not going to review every product at Amazon; we've given you some hints on what to look for, or buy from a source where you trust they will give you what you asked for.

Comment: @keshlam - Thanks , Actually manage to find a product. Once again thanks for your insights